# Why am I getting this error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, valueerror

I'm currently working on a project looking into how star forming regions can be obscured by dust in the galactic centre and need to simulate a star forming region to run further tests on. I've made my star forming region using the multivariate gaussian probability function, this takes three inputs namely 'x', 'mu' and 'cov'. Basically, I want to generate multiple star forming regions and add them together, each star forming region having its own 'x', 'mu' and 'cov'. In my case, 'x' and 'mu' need to be a column vectors and 'cov' needs to be a 3x3 matrix. At the moment, my code is giving me an error  on this line: `grid[i,j,k] += pdf_multivariate_gauss(vect, mu_in, cov_in)` and I have no clue how to go about solving it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from scipy import linalg

def pdf_multivariate_gauss(x, mu, cov):
    '''
    Calculate the multivariate normal density (pdf)

    Keyword arguments:
        x = numpy array of a "d x 1" sample vector
        mu = numpy array of a "d x 1" mean vector
        cov = "numpy array of a d x d" covariance matrix
    '''
    'mu must be a column vector'
    'x must be a column vector'
    'covariance matrix must be square'
    'cov_mat and mu_vec must have the same dimensions'
    'mu and x must have the same dimensions'
    part1 = 1 / ((2*np.pi)**(len(mu)/2))*(linalg.det(cov))         # Defining the two halves of the equation separately
    part2 = -0.5*((x-mu).T).dot(linalg.inv(cov)).dot(x-mu)   # .linalg is the package with matrix operations in
    return np.sqrt(part1) * np.exp(part2)                          # Multiplying the two halves together

n = 100                           # Defines the for loop boundaries, will have to be much bigger for real thing
n_core = 5          
vect = np.zeros(3)                # A dx1 array of vector values, each run of loop will produce 1 vector
grid = np.zeros([100,100,100])    # Defining space to plot the Gaussian inside 
c_dens = np.zeros([100,100])      # Defining a space to plot column density

for i in range(n):
    x = 0 + i*0.1 + 0.5*0.1       # Will have to code values for dx, dy and dz rather than hard coding them
    for j in range(n):            # Can reduce size of grid to make it run faster
        y = 0 + j*0.1 + 0.5*0.1   # To generalise into 3D just add another vect[2] = z, have to make grid() 3D too
        for k in range(n):
            z = 0 + k*0.1 + 0.5*0.1
            vect[0] = x
            vect[1] = y
            vect[2] = z
            for l in range(n_core):
                mu = np.random.uniform(0,10,(n_core,3,1))  # Controls the 'position' of the gaussian core
                cov = np.random.uniform(0,10,(n_core,3,3)) # Contols the shape of the gaussian core, off axis elements to zero for circle     
                mu_in = mu[l,:,:]
                cov_in = cov[l,:,:]
                grid[i,j,k] += pdf_multivariate_gauss(vect, mu_in, cov_in)
        c_dens[i,j] = np.sum(grid[i,j,:])*0.1       # Column density map is summation of i and j components of grid multiplied by dz
    
print("grid", grid)

plt.clf()
im = plt.imshow(image, aspect='auto', cmap='magma', origin='upper')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a full traceback in a code block so we can help you with your code.

Comment: You buried the error location in a long paragraph, most of which is not relevant to the immediate error.  A quick read suggests that `grid[i,j,k]` is a single value location, but RHS of that equation probably is creating multiple values, an array, or what the error describes generically as a `sequence`.

Comment: The first step to solving a bug like this is to understand it.  Focus on the nature and shape of the terms in question.  Getting shapes right if often 80% of the debugging battle in `numpy`.